# Android studio Application running issu in Android emulator

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

Error 1 retrieving device properties for emulator-5554:
adb.exe: device still authorizing

Launching lib\main.dart on emulator-5554 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.3

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 37s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

i got this error for the long time in android studio im running my application in web and desktop and it will run it and when ever i try to run application in android emulator or my physical device it gives me an this error i try to resolve this error too many time and i also chake gradl things but still i got this error i didn't know what is this error can anyone give me solution with the explanation im new in flutter development and i heat this gradel errors

for this error i first try to resolve with getting suggestion from the ai tool like cpt or gool gemine but thir solution wouldn't worked after i came at this platform and also i cant understand this so I'm questioning this problams